# Trying to write my own Neural Network in Python

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network

Last semester I took an online machine learning course from Standford taught by Professor Ng. http://www.ml-class.org/course/auth/welcome I thought it was pretty informative.  To brush up/understand neural networks better I tried to write my own in python.  Here it is:

```
import numpy

class NN:

    def __init__(self, sl):

        #sl = number of units (not counting bias unit) in layer l
        self.sl = sl
        self.layers = len(sl)

        #Create weights
        self.weights = []
        for idx in range(1, self.layers):
            self.weights.append(numpy.matrix(numpy.random.rand(self.sl[idx-1]+1, self.sl[idx])/5))

        self.cost = []

    def update(self, input):

        if input.shape[1] != self.sl[0]:
            raise ValueError, 'The first layer must have a node for every feature'

        self.z = []
        self.a = []

        #Input activations.  I'm expecting inputs as numpy matrix (Examples x Featrues) 
        self.a.append(numpy.hstack((numpy.ones((input.shape[0], 1)), input)))#Set inputs ai + bias unit

        #Hidden activations
        for weight in self.weights:         
            self.z.append(self.a[-1]*weight)
            self.a.append(numpy.hstack((numpy.ones((self.z[-1].shape[0], 1)), numpy.tanh(self.z[-1])))) #tanh is a fancy sigmoid

        #Output activation
        self.a[-1] = self.z[-1] #Not logistic regression thus no sigmoid function
        del self.z[-1]

    def backPropagate(self, targets, lamda):

        m = float(targets.shape[0]) #m is number of examples

        #Calculate cost
        Cost = -1/m*sum(numpy.power(self.a[-1] - targets, 2))
        for weight in self.weights:
            Cost = Cost + lamda/(2*m)*numpy.power(weight[1:, :], 2).sum()
        self.cost.append(abs(float(Cost)))

        #Calculate error for each layer
        delta = []
        delta.append(self.a[-1] - targets)
        for idx in range(1, self.layers-1): #No delta for the input layer because it is the input
            weight = self.weights[-idx][1:, :] #Ignore bias unit
            dsigmoid = numpy.multiply(self.a[-(idx+1)][:,1:], 1-self.a[-(idx+1)][:,1:]) #dsigmoid is a(l).*(1-a(l))
            delta.append(numpy.multiply(delta[-1]*weight.T, dsigmoid)) #Ignore Regularization

        Delta = []
        for idx in range(self.layers-1):
            Delta.append(self.a[idx].T*delta[-(idx+1)])

        self.weight_gradient = []
        for idx in range(len(Delta)):
            self.weight_gradient.append(numpy.nan_to_num(1/m*Delta[idx] + numpy.vstack((numpy.zeros((1, self.weights[idx].shape[1])), lamda/m*self.weights[idx][1:, :]))))

    def train(self, input, targets, alpha, lamda, iterations = 1000):

        #alpha: learning rate
        #lamda: regularization term

        for i in range(iterations):
            self.update(input)
            self.backPropagate(targets, lamda)
            self.weights = [self.weights[idx] - alpha*self.weight_gradient[idx] for idx in range(len(self.weights))]

    def predict(self, input):

        self.update(input)
        return self.a[-1]
```

But it doesn't work =(.  Inspecting the cost vs. iteration I can see a blip in the cost and the prediction for A is all the same.  Can someone help me understand why my neural network is not converging?

Thanks,
Sorry about the amount of code (maybe someone will find it useful).

Update:

Instead of using random data I've got some structured data from the UCI Machine Learning Repository.  The particular data set is the burned area of forest fires, in the northeast region of Portugal, using meteorological and other data: http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Forest+Fires I modified the data so that days and months were numbers: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Am3oTptaLsExdC1PeXl1eTczRnRNejl3QUo5RjNLVVE

```
data = numpy.loadtxt(open('FF-data.csv', 'rb'), delimiter = ',', skiprows = 1)
features = data[:,0:11]
targets = numpy.matrix(data[:,12]).T

nfeatures = (features-features.mean(axis=0))/features.std(axis=0)

n = NN([11, 10, 1]) #The class takes the list of how many nodes in each layer
n.train(nfeatures, targets, 0.003, 0.0)

import matplotlib.pyplot
matplotlib.pyplot.subplot(221)
matplotlib.pyplot.plot(n.cost)
matplotlib.pyplot.title('Cost vs. Iteration')

matplotlib.pyplot.subplot(222)
matplotlib.pyplot.scatter(n.predict(nfeatures), targets)
matplotlib.pyplot.title('Data vs. Predicted')

matplotlib.pyplot.savefig('Report.png', format = 'png')
matplotlib.pyplot.close()
```

Why does the cost bottom out around 4000 and why does the Data Vs. Predicted not have any trend?  You can see the graphs here: https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B23oTptaLsExMTQ0OTAxNWEtYjE2NS00MjA5LTg1MjMtNDBhYjVmMTFhZDhm

Comment: I ran your code on some simple examples, and it seems that it's working all right. Why do you think it's not working? In your example the cost decreases very fast in the first hundred iterations and then stays about the same, which is, I'd say, the expected behaviour.

Comment: Thanks for running my code.  Could you check with your trained network what the output of n.predict(A) is?  For me all the predicted values are the same regardless of input features (usually close to the average(Targets).  For example Targets = [4, 5, 6,7] n.predict(features) = [5.5, 5.5, 5.5, 5.5].

Comment: Use pandas for time-series data!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The neural network was unable to train on the Forest Fire data https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Am3oTptaLsExdC1PeXl1eTczRnRNejl3QUo5RjNLVVE for a few reasons.

First the numpy.tanh() sigmoid function is not behaving as expected.  The code should be changed from:

```
self.a.append(numpy.hstack((numpy.ones((self.z[-1].shape[0], 1)),numpy.tanh(self.z[-1])))) #tanh is a fancy sigmoid
```

To:

```
self.a.append(numpy.hstack((numpy.ones((self.z[-1].shape[0], 1)), 1/(1+numpy.exp(-self.z[-1])))))
```

Second numpy and matplotlib are not playing nice.  The numpy matrices seem to be plotted backwards.  This can be fixed by using matrix.tolist().  Code changed from:

```
matplotlib.pyplot.scatter(n.predict(nfeatures), targets)
```

To:

```
matplotlib.pyplot.scatter(n.predict(nfeatures).tolist(), targets.tolist())
```

Finally the number of nodes should be approximately 10% of the example size.  Instead of 10 it is better to use 50 nodes.

The working neural network code is posted below with a new function autoparam which tries to find the best learning rate and regularization constant.  You can see the graphs for the Forest Fire cost vs iteration and data vs predicted here: https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B23oTptaLsExMWQ4ZWM1ODYtZDMzMC00M2VkLWI1OWUtYzg3NzgxNWYyMTIy

Thanks for reading!  I hope my neural network can help people.

```
import numpy

class NN:

    def __init__(self, sl):

        #sl = number of units (not counting bias unit) in layer l
        self.sl = sl
        self.layers = len(sl)

        #Create weights
        self.weights = []
        for idx in range(1, self.layers):
            self.weights.append(numpy.matrix(numpy.random.rand(self.sl[idx-1]+1, self.sl[idx]))/5)

        self.cost = []

    def update(self, input):

        if input.shape[1] != self.sl[0]:
            raise ValueError, 'The first layer must have a node for every feature'

        self.z = []
        self.a = []

        #Input activations.  Expected inputs as numpy matrix (Examples x Featrues) 
        self.a.append(numpy.hstack((numpy.ones((input.shape[0], 1)), input)))#Set inputs ai + bias unit

        #Hidden activations
        for weight in self.weights: 
            self.z.append(self.a[-1]*weight)
            self.a.append(numpy.hstack((numpy.ones((self.z[-1].shape[0], 1)), 1/(1+numpy.exp(-self.z[-1]))))) #sigmoid

        #Output activation
        self.a[-1] = self.z[-1] #Not logistic regression thus no sigmoid function
        del self.z[-1]

    def backPropagate(self, targets, lamda):

        m = float(targets.shape[0]) #m is number of examples

        #Calculate cost
        Cost = -1/m*sum(numpy.power(self.a[-1] - targets, 2))
        for weight in self.weights:
            Cost = Cost + lamda/(2*m)*numpy.power(weight[1:, :], 2).sum()
        self.cost.append(abs(float(Cost)))

        #Calculate error for each layer
        delta = []
        delta.append(self.a[-1] - targets)
        for idx in range(1, self.layers-1): #No delta for the input layer because it is the input
            weight = self.weights[-idx][1:, :] #Ignore bias unit
            dsigmoid = numpy.multiply(self.a[-(idx+1)][:,1:], 1-self.a[-(idx+1)][:,1:]) #dsigmoid is a(l).*(1-a(l))
            delta.append(numpy.multiply(delta[-1]*weight.T, dsigmoid)) #Ignore Regularization

        Delta = []
        for idx in range(self.layers-1):
            Delta.append(self.a[idx].T*delta[-(idx+1)])

        self.weight_gradient = []
        for idx in range(len(Delta)):
            self.weight_gradient.append(numpy.nan_to_num(1/m*Delta[idx] + numpy.vstack((numpy.zeros((1, self.weights[idx].shape[1])), lamda/m*self.weights[idx][1:, :]))))

    def train(self, input, targets, alpha, lamda, iterations = 1000):

        #alpha: learning rate
        #lamda: regularization term

        for i in range(iterations):
            self.update(input)
            self.backPropagate(targets, lamda)
            self.weights = [self.weights[idx] - alpha*self.weight_gradient[idx] for idx in range(len(self.weights))]

    def autoparam(self, data, alpha = [0.001, 0.003, 0.01, 0.03, 0.1, 0.3], lamda = [0.001, 0.003, 0.01, 0.03, 0.1, 0.3, 1, 3, 10]):

        #data: numpy matrix with targets in last column
        #alpha: learning rate
        #lamda: regularization term

        #Create training, cross validation, and test sets
        while 1:
            try:
                numpy.seterr(invalid = 'raise')
                numpy.random.shuffle(data) #Shuffle data
                training_set = data[0:data.shape[0]/10*6, 0:-1]
                self.ntraining_set = (training_set-training_set.mean(axis=0))/training_set.std(axis=0)
                self.training_tgt = numpy.matrix(data[0:data.shape[0]/10*6, -1]).T

                cv_set = data[data.shape[0]/10*6:data.shape[0]/10*8, 0:-1]
                self.ncv_set = (cv_set-cv_set.mean(axis=0))/cv_set.std(axis=0)
                self.cv_tgt = numpy.matrix(data[data.shape[0]/10*6:data.shape[0]/10*8, -1]).T

                test_set = data[data.shape[0]/10*8:, 0:-1]
                self.ntest_set = (test_set-test_set.mean(axis=0))/test_set.std(axis=0)
                self.test_tgt = numpy.matrix(data[data.shape[0]/10*8:, -1]).T

                break

            except FloatingPointError:
                pass

        numpy.seterr(invalid = 'warn')
        cost = 999999
        for i in alpha:
            for j in lamda:
                self.__init__(self.sl)
                self.train(self.ntraining_set, self.training_tgt, i, j, 2000)
                current_cost = 1/float(cv_set.shape[0])*sum(numpy.square(self.predict(self.ncv_set) - self.cv_tgt)).tolist()[0][0]
                print current_cost
                if current_cost < cost:
                    cost = current_cost
                    self.learning_rate = i
                    self.regularization = j
        self.__init__(self.sl)

    def predict(self, input):

        self.update(input)
        return self.a[-1]
```

Loading data, Plotting, etc...

```
data = numpy.loadtxt(open('FF-data.csv', 'rb'), delimiter = ',', skiprows = 1)#Load
numpy.random.shuffle(data)

features = data[:,0:11]
nfeatures = (features-features.mean(axis=0))/features.std(axis=0)
targets = numpy.matrix(data[:, 12]).T

n = NN([11, 50, 1])

n.train(nfeatures, targets, 0.07, 0.0, 2000)

import matplotlib.pyplot
matplotlib.pyplot.subplot(221)
matplotlib.pyplot.plot(n.cost)
matplotlib.pyplot.title('Cost vs. Iteration')

matplotlib.pyplot.subplot(222)
matplotlib.pyplot.scatter(n.predict(nfeatures).tolist(), targets.tolist())
matplotlib.pyplot.plot(targets.tolist(), targets.tolist(), c = 'r')
matplotlib.pyplot.title('Data vs. Predicted')

matplotlib.pyplot.savefig('Report.png', format = 'png')
matplotlib.pyplot.close()
```

Answer (score 7):

(Sorry, I don't have enough rep to add comments, so I'll just keep posting answers instead.)

Yes, it does seem strange. If, however, after training you generate a new matrix B:

```
B = numpy.random.rand(5, 4)/5
Targets = B*X
print n.predict(B)
print B*X
```

it will work fine (most of the times - sometimes it will still give the average(Targets) as the answer).
Note: I switched from using 100 features to using just 4 in my example.

Also, I don't think that running 5000 iterations on 50 elements of the data set will do you any good. You should generally try to use as much training data as you can - and here you can use as much as you want, but you use even less examples than you have features.

This is fun, I'll think about it some more :) I was using your network for a more simple example - as Input I provided two numbers, and expected their sum as Output. It worked more or less okay.

Comment: Hi.  I trimmed the number of iterations back to the default 1000 and got a larger structured data set (518 examples).

Answer (score -1):

I think that your bias should be subtracted somewhere from the weighted inputs (or set to -1). From what I see in your code, the neurons add all the inputs, including the bias (which is set to +1.

Comment: these are not statistics, the bias is to be added and learned. Could you explain why you think it would help ?